# Apply a function to a list and pass its result to a constructor?

Tags: list, haskell, constructor, quadtree

How can just write `flipv`one time applying it to each element of list `[se, sq, nw, ne]`, giving the result (not as a list of course) to the `Q` constructor?

```
data (Eq a, Show a) => QT a = C a | Q (QT a) (QT a) (QT a) (QT a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)

flipv :: (Eq a, Show a) => QT a -> QT a
flipv (C a) = C a
flipv (Q nw ne se sw) = Q (flipv se) (flipv sw) (flipv nw) (flipv ne)
```

**EDIT**: note this actually wrong because the pointers should be: NW NE SW SE.

Comment: +1, because I had fun trying to answer it =)

Comment: BTW, you should drop the `(Eq a, Show a) =>` from the `data` type. See http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types for an explanation (after "However, it's a very strong convention in Haskell to never add typeclass constraints in data declarations...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no particularly simple or compact method, but you could try this:

```
flipv :: (Eq a, Show a) => QT a -> QT a
flipv (C a) = C a
flipv (Q nw ne se sw) = Q se' sw' nw' ne'
  where [nw', ne', se', sw'] = map flipv [nw, ne, se, sw]
```

Comment: @Gremo, looks pretty nice to me.  Maybe your eyes need training.  Or it may look ugly to you because you are expecting something simpler -- but what you desire is not expressible in the type system.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I was going to suggest `toList` and `fromList`. It's more code, but it enables elegant composition in the end.

```
toList :: QT a -> [QT a]
toList (Q w x y z) = [w,x,y,z]

fromList :: [QT a] -> QT a
fromList [w,x,y,z] = Q w x y z

listOpOnQT :: ([QT a] -> [QT a]) -> QT a -> QT a
listOpOnQT _ (C a) = C a
listOpOnQT f q     = fromList . map (listOpOnQT f) . f . toList $ q

flipv :: QT a -> QT a
flipv = listOpOnQT reverse
```

Loosely tested in ghci

```
ghci> let q = Q (Q (C 1) (C 2) (C 3) (C 4)) (C 22) (C 33) (C 44)
ghci> q
Q (Q (C 1) (C 2) (C 3) (C 4)) (C 22) (C 33) (C 44)
ghci> flipv q
Q (C 44) (C 33) (C 22) (Q (C 4) (C 3) (C 2) (C 1))
```

You can easily make 'sort' work on your QT structure as well, now.

```
import Data.List (sort)
instance (Ord a) => Ord (QT a) where
    compare (C x) (C y) = x `compare` y
    compare (C x) _ = LT
    compare _ (C x) = GT
    compare _ _ = EQ

sortv :: (Ord a) => QT a -> QT a
sortv = listOpOnQT sort
```

Tested as part of the previous ghci session...

```
ghci> sortv it
Q (C 22) (C 33) (C 44) (Q (C 1) (C 2) (C 3) (C 4))
ghci> sortv q
Q (C 22) (C 33) (C 44) (Q (C 1) (C 2) (C 3) (C 4))
```

Notice sorting the flipped q and just plain q both came out with the same result (therefore the sorting probably works! yay). You might want to pick a better implementation of `compare`, I just threw that one together to see stuff happen.

---

**So how does it work?**

The magic sauce, as you might have guessed, is `listOpOnQT`. In the non-trivial case, it turns the QT structure into a list, applies the listy function to the list, maps the *lifted* listy function on all elements of the list, and then pulls the list back into a QT structure. A better name for `listOpOnQT` might be `liftQT`, though it only works for a very special kind of function...

Comment: this is actually a nice answer, but not THE answer. I was looking for something concise and in-line, I mean without using any additional function apart from standard prelude.

Comment: @Gremo yeah I figured as much. I started out trying to see if something like `fmap` would do the trick, but unless you make QT an instance of a couple classes, then there's not much you can do out of the box (afaik).

Comment: I object to this ad-hoc `Ord` instance.  I would prefer to write a separate compare function, eg. `compareLeaves` and use `sortBy`.  This `Ord` instance does not respect the extension of the data type (and, IMO, is hardly natural).  Otherwise nice answer.

Comment: @luqui Yeah, the `Ord` instance doesn't really fit. I just wanted to demonstrate the ease of lifting `[a] -> [a]` functions (that do not change the length of the list), but `sort` was the only other one I could think of that fit this parenthetical constraint.

Answer (score 1):

There's basically no simple way to do it without enumerating all four arguments, because otherwise, how can you make sure that the list has the right number (4) of elements?

Answer (score -1):

> applying it to each element of list [se, sq, nw, ne], giving the result (not as a list of course) to the Q constructor?

takes a list and throws a QT.

```
data (Eq a, Show a) => QT a = C a | Q (QT a) (QT a) (QT a) (QT a)  
     deriving (Eq, Show)

flipv :: (Eq a, Show a) => [a] -> QT a  
flipv [nw, ne, se, sw] = Q (C se) (C sw) (C nw) (C ne)

main = do  
    print (Q (C 1) (C 2) (C 3) (C 4))  
    (print . flipv) [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: not what I mean, that is simplify `Q (flipv se) (flipv sw) (flipv nw) (flipv ne)`.